# Compute the CCDF of $p(x)=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{k!}{(k+n-m)!} [L_k^{n-m}(x)]^2 x^{n-m} e^{-x}$

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function, integral

I have the following PDF:
\begin{align}
p(x)=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{k!}{(k+n-m)!} [L_k^{n-m}(x)]^2 x^{n-m} e^{-x}, \quad \quad x \ge 0,
\end{align} 
where $L_k^{n-m}(x)$ is the associated Laguerre polynomial of order $k$ and $n \ge m$

I need to compute the corresponding CCDF $\left( \text{i.e.} \, P(x \ge a) \right)$.

My attempt:
$P(x \ge a)=\int_a^\infty p(x) dx=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{k!}{(k+n-m)!} \int_a^\infty [L_k^{n-m}(x)]^2 x^{n-m} e^{-x} dx $. I am not sure if I have the right to switch between the sum and the integral. The problem is that
I am not able to compute this integral, but I found (in the table of integrals) that $\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha} e^{-x} [L_n^\alpha (x)]^2 dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+n+1) }{n! }$, with $\alpha>0$.
How to continue the calculations ?

Comment: I posted this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438296/ccdf-of-px-frac1m-sum-k-1m-1-frackkn-m-l-kn-mx2) but did not get any attention. P.S. I don't know if this is the proper way to link the two questions..

Comment: Can you compute $\int_a^\infty x^ke^{-x}dx$, for integer $k$? If so, substitute formula for Laguerre polynomial and calculate the integral. It will be tedious, but doable.

Comment: Because the sum is finite, there is no difficulty interchanging the sum and the integral.  (One proof proceeds by induction on $m$, with the case $m=3$, corresponding to a sum of two integrals, following from the linearity of integration.)